# Pip Install Error Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, pip

I'm currently using Ubuntu 16.04 and Python 2.7.

After trying to install pip I get the following error

```
~$ sudo apt-get install python-pip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-pip : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
          Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
          Recommends: python-all-dev (>= 2.6) but it is not going to 
be installed
          Recommends: python-setuptools but it is not going to be 
installed
          Recommends: python-wheel but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I made sure everything was updated by running

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade --yes
```

I also got curl and aptitude and ran those in their respective methods to install pip. Lastly I uninstalled Python and reinstalled it. All to no avail. Any solutions?

Comment: Are there any held packages in the results of running the command `dpkg --get-selections | grep hold` ?

Comment: Try installing python-dev:
`sudo apt install python-dev`

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't have the right version of python installed. You probably want 2.7 for pip.

```
sudo apt-get install python-minimal
```

this should give you recommended version. But if that version above 2.76 do this:

```
wget  https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.6/Python-2.7.6.tgz  
./configure
make
make install
```

Then i would also install build-essential.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Then to switch python versions

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python
```

After this install pip

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```